# Hide element when touch outside of element without triggering new action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I have a popover that shows up when a image is hovered. On desktop it works fine as expected when the mouse is hovered over the image.

However, on mobile, I would like to have the popover to open on one tap, and then close when clicked anywhere outside of the popover on the screen.

However, the tricky part is, since the images is placed on a grid close together, clicking outside of the popover would likely trigger another popover to open for another image closeby. Ideally, I would like to close the popover without having it triggering another event of opening up another popover. To trigger another popover, the user would have to click again.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/allenchuang/hwu81fpq/

fiddle result: http://jsfiddle.net/allenchuang/hwu81fpq/embedded/result/

Here's what I come up with so far using jQuery..

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {
  var container = $(".pop-over");
  while(container.parent().is(":hover")) {
      // if the target click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
      {
          e.preventDefault();
          container.hide();                  
      }
  }
});
```

CURRENT BEHAVIOR: click on img1 -> opens popover1 -> click on img2 (or anyother element in body) -> closes popover1 but opens popover2.

IDEAL BEHAVIOR: click on img1 -> opens popover1 -> click on img2 (or anyother element in body) -> closes popover1 ( to trigger popover2 you need to click on image2 again)

Comment: I think you just need to update `while(container.parent().is(":hover")) {` to cover mobile devices. I can't test on mobile but maybe `while(container.is(":visible")) {` would work. Also I don't think `:hover` css is that reliable on mobile devices

Comment: it doesnt seem to work even with visible. Does preventDefault stop hover from firing? :)

Comment: I don't think that solution works. It does fire into a hover state but the popover is hidden before it shows...